# Sorting multi index pandas by subgroup then by group with highest value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

I want to expand on resetting indexes, sorting values and setting new indexs for MultiIndex DataFrames.

I want to take this

```
df = df.reset_index()
       .sort_values(['col1','col3'], ascending=[True, False])
       .set_index(['col1','col2'])

           col3 
col1 col2       
a    t     2.92
     1     1.67
     2     0.75
     3     0.50 
b    t     4.75
     2     2.25
     3     2.00
     1     0.50 
c    t     7.90
     3     2.75
     1     2.65
     2     2.50
```

and sort by the sorted groups highest value

```
           col3
col1 col2      
c    t     7.90
     3     2.75
     1     2.65
     2     2.50
b    t     4.75
     2     2.25
     3     2.00
     1     0.50
a    t     2.92
     1     1.67
     2     0.75
     3     0.50
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by temporary assigning a sortkey, the sortkey is created by `groupby` level=0 index or 'col1' then `transform` and summing:

```
df.assign(sortkey=df[['col3']].groupby(level=0).transform('sum'))\
  .sort_values(['sortkey','col3'], ascending=[False,False])\
  .drop('sortkey', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
           col3
col1 col2      
c    t     7.90
     3     2.75
     1     2.65
     2     2.50
b    t     4.75
     2     2.25
     3     2.00
     1     0.50
a    t     2.92
     1     1.67
     2     0.75
     3     0.50
```